# Using Google Tests in embedded target?

Tags: unit-testing, embedded, googletest, target

I have started using google tests and google mocks in my embedded project.
Everything works fine, but currently I use it on my host machine when I develop code. It is the best option for TDD (it's fast), but I have to ocassionally run all code on the target board (STM32), because on my PC I use GCC, on the target ARMclang. So I need to validate that everything works fine on the target as well.

Here comes my question regarding Google Tests:

Is it possible to easily redirect all debug messages (test results) to a different peripherels than std::ostream, i.e. UART or USB so I could send test results to my host computer back?

I guess so, but there is quite a lot of code, it will take me weeks to dig into that and make it working. Maybe someone did that before and could give me hints which files need to be modified and replaced with my hardware wrappers? And does it makes a sense, or it is too complex (maybe there is to many OS dependencies) and it would be better to use another framework like CppuTest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you build a test for your target system? Are all references resolved by the linker? If not, are there some methods or functions in the context of `cout`? -- I did a few projects in similar situations, but mostly in plain C. Most target libraries allow user-defined low-level functions for files, for example `write()`. -- Anyway, why would you want to run the tests on the target? Do you suspect the compiler to have bugs?

Comment: The reason why I need to run the tests on the target is that I got this requirement from my CTO because of IEC 62304 standard - we have to apply it to the software lifecycle.I don't know if it is so mandatory, but I promised to make a research on that and try to run tests on the target. At the moment I was able to run tests compiled with arm-none-eabi-gcc. I tried to capture data from the output stream using printf() and semihosting (it is supported in OCD). And it works! In next few days I will try to improve that and describe solution in my first post, maybe it will be usefull for someone...

Comment: Sounds good! You can answer your own question, and even mark it, after some time. Please do this, so that others can easily spot this from the list of questions.